# передавать структуры в функции или вкладывать функции в структуры C++

Tags: c++, struct

Всем привет, возникла у меня необходимость в функции для работы с данными из структуры. Я решил сделать функцию частью структуры, у меня сразу возник вопрос: "А правильно ли я сделал" или лучше создать отдельно функцию которая будет принимать структуру как параметр. Что все таки лучше?

Comment: Философски замечу, что даже если будет создана панацея от всех болезней, появятся болезни типа передоза панацеей... Лучше то, что в большей степени подходит для вашей конкретной задачи. Если было бы "лучше" для всех случаев - то "хуже" в язык бы не вошло :)

Comment: Вообще-то для таких случаев в С++ специально сделаны классы.

Comment: Знаете, вы бы лучше сказали что вам мешает произвольно выбирать из этих двух - тогда уже можно будет говорить об их плюсах и минусах

Answer (score 0):

На мой взгляд,предпочтительнее создавать функцию внутри структуры, чтобы избежать расходов на передачу аргументов и не забивать пространство имён. С другой стороны если этой функции придётся работать не только с этой структурой, то в таком случае лучше объявить функцию вне структуры.

Comment: [ООП за и против](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&hl=ru&biw=1429&bih=871&sxsrf=ACYBGNS2zfY5UG9JcRGkrZsN3ST7dpkWDA%3A1570984067167&ei=g1CjXd_zCbLCmwWimI2oBw&q=%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BF+%D0%B7%D0%B0+%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2&oq=%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%BF+%D0%B7%D0%B0+%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2&gs_l=psy-ab.3..0i22i30.1621787.1627933..1628843...0.2..0.84.952.15......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i71j0i131j0j0i67j0i10j33i22i29i30.hoCAMPkI1o4&ved=0ahUKEwifwZXa05nlAhUy4aYKHSJMA3UQ4dUDCAo&uact=5)